# Scala: cyclomatic complexity too high for pattern matching case classes

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a few case classes like:

```
case class TypeX(a: Int, b: Int, c: String)
sealed trait metrictypes
object metrictypes {
  case class SuccessCount(a: TypeX) extends metrictypes
  case class FailureCount(a: TypeX) extends metrictypes
  case class WarningCount(a: TypeX) extends metrictypes
     .....
```

I have 10 such case classes ^

I have some functionality which results in a list `collectedList` of type List[metrictypes]. For example:

`List(SuccessCount(TypeX(111, 222, "abc")), WarningCount(TypeX(999, 777, "zzz")))`

I need to count metrictype and also collect TypeX in a list `finalList`. I'm doing something like:

```
  val finalList = new ListBuffer[TypeX]()
  val result = collectedList {x =>
    x match {
      case SuccessCount(a)  => incrementSuccessCount(); finalList += a
      case FailureCount(a)  => incrementFailureCount(); finalList += a
      .... (10 times)
      case _ => println("Unknown!")

    }
  }
```

I know this isn't the cleanest or efficient way to do it and it also results in a high cyclomatic complexity. How can I improve this?

I also tried grouping them based on the metrictypes by doing:

```
  val groupedList = collectedList.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _))
```

This results in

```
Map(SuccessCount(TypeX(111, 222, "abc")) -> 1, WarningCount(TypeX(999, 777, "zzz")) -> 1))
```

Still unable to figure out how I can get the counts of occurrences for metrictypes AND collect TypeX only in a list.

Answer (score 2):

What about if you change your design a little to something like this:

```scala
final case class TypeX(a: Int, b: Int, c: String)

sealed trait MetricType
object MetricType {
  final case object Success extends MetricType
  final case object Failure extends MetricType
  final case object Warning extends MetricType
}

final case class MetricCount(tpe: MetricType, a: TypeX)
```

Which then you could use like this:

```scala
def processCounts(data: List[MetricCount]): (List[TypeX], Map[MetricType, Int]) = {
  val finalList = data.map(_.a)
  val countsByMetricType = data.groupMapReduce(_.tpe)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
  
  finalList -> countsByMetricType
}
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the data within your case classes actually have a data of `TypeX` then you should use the `metrictype` trait to generalize that all of your case classes has an `a: TypeX` then you can just `map` your `collectedList` to `a` rather than having to pattern-match all of it.

On the other hand, on collecting a specific kind of data on your list.
Since we want to be able to collect based on the type rather than the data.
It would be better for you to do a `collect` on your `collectedList` and partial match on the types you are chasing for ala

```
val successList = collectedList.collect { case i: SuccessCount => i }
val warningList = collectedList.collect { case i: WarningCount => i }
```

You could even generalize this by creating yourself a helper function of:

```
def collectByType[B <: A](collectedList: List[A]): List[B] =
  collectedList.collect{ case i: B => i }
val successList = collectByType[SuccessCount](collectedList)
val warningList = collectByType[WarningCount](collectedList)
```